# installing a vm machine for macos x

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

Well these are the instructions I use:

```
 You will need about 25 -30 gb free on your disk.
1) Download and Install the open source Virtual Box of Oracle.
Win platform download
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.1.6/VirtualBox-4.1.6-74713-Win.exe

2) Download and Install the Extra pack for all platforms
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.6-74713.vbox-extpack

I think that except from Virtual Boxing you can use Blangsak as a native install as i think it says it is Hackintosh but you might need to do some changes to your machine that might not be of your will and you might not really want it right now. Anyway using a VM will keep you away from these problems.

3) Download blangsak lion v3 or v2 (i used v2 maybe v3 is better)
v3 blangsak http://isohunt.com/torrent_details/348643909/blangsak?tab=summary
v2 blangsak

4) Then we need to configure the Virtual Box. I suppose you have already downloaded and installed the Virtual Box and the extension pack of it.
5) Create a New Vmachine with the Virtual machine wizard with the name of your choice and let the operating system be Mac OS X and its Version Mac OS X Server 64 bit. All these should not be different.
6) Then assign to it sth more than 1gb ram. maybe 1.2 to 1.5 is optimal. you can change it afterwards if a problem occurs.
7) Create a new start up disk choosing next. Let it be 200gb virtually. Do not worry it is not going to be that much actually.
8) Let it be a .vmdk file
9) then press next (dynamically allocated won't hurt..if you find sth better tell me)
10) You should then be able to create the new virtual machine.

After the virtual machine is created we should configure it.
1) Right click and Press the settings of the virtual machine you created.
2) Go to the system tab and on Motherboard disable Floppy support and enable the "Enable IO APIC" and "Enable Absolute Pointing Device" chipset should be ICH9. Disable the EFI loader.
3) Go to processors. For intel Core 2 duo processors should be 1. The intel i-Series might be able to use more. Disable the PAE on the Extended features on processor...it will slow down the vm.
4) Enable on Acceleration tab the "Enable Nested paging" "Enable VT-x/AMD-V"
5) On display use full video memory. as much (128 mb maybe) and enable 3d acceleration it won't hurt.
$$$$STUCK IN HERE$$$$$$
    6) On Storage tab on your left add an IDE controller with Blangsak v2 or v3 iso. You should also see if there is a Sata Controller with the virtual hard drive we created before. (you might also be able to the bootable of blangSak as a sata controller image without an ide controller-it might be faster..that is why i am mentioning it. at least for the installation proccess-experiment do not worry)
    7) As far as i am concerned there is nothing more on the configuration side to be done.
    8) Try saving the configurations and run the machine.

A window should appear if you wait with the BlangSak Lion v2 caption on a Disk. You press Enter an Apple appears and then it is a matter of time to see the language bar appear so that you should continue installing the mac os X lion operating system on your virtual machine. Then it is easy.

the are no password for mahmood user that appear. (blank password) You can always change the name that appears and put a password. On the appstore you should be able to create an apple account with your name and credit card and download for free the Xcode 4.2.
After installing when you power off your machine and then power it back on you use the macOs lion X icon (X icon ) by using arrows instead of the disk icon that appears and pressing enter.
```

I got stuck in the point I mentioned. The image I see is this:[image]

So, what to do?? I do not see anywhere the blankgsack, even if I deleted the IDE controller and created a new one. Where am I supposed to see this as an option?

Comment: create a cd/dvd drive and assign the banksack iso to it as virtual dvd content. you are aware, that mac osx is not allowed to be run on a virtual machine?

Comment: you mean legally? :$ no I wasn't aware, thx for the info.

Comment: they want to sell their crazily expensive computers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on IDE Controller and choose "add CD/DVD drive". In the upcoming dialog press "choose medium" and then select the banksack iso file.